# Disable hashing on Auth::attempt

Tags: laravel, authentication

I am working with an old database without hashed passwords, also this database needs to be unhashed since it is connected to a Runnable JAR.

I did everything to connect it with Laravel 5.3 and it worked, but.. When comes to login it always return false.

Here is the function code:

```
public function login(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request, [
        'account' => 'required|alpha_num|exists:accounts,account',
        'password' => 'required|alpha_num|min:4',
    ]);


    if(Auth::attempt(['account' => $request->account, 'password' => $request->password])){
        return redirect()->route('account');
    }

    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

I came to the conclusion that Auth::attempt hashes the given password through the view and when comparing to the unhashed one in the database, returns false.

How can i fix this??

Thank you.

Answer (score 12):

You will need to use another method of [manual authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#other-authentication-methods).

```
$user = User::where('account', $request->account)
            ->where('password', $request->password)
            ->first();

if($user) {
    Auth::loginUsingId($user->id);
    // -- OR -- //
    Auth::login($user);
    return redirect()->route('account');
} else {
    return redirect()->back()->withInput();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You just can add this to your App/User. 
If you are using another driver in config/hashing.php  - change bcrypt to argon/argon2i

```html
public function getAuthPassword() {
    return bcrypt($this->password);
}
```