# how to remove hash from laravel 5.8 | i want to remove laravel hash form from login and register

Tags: laravel

**i want remove laravel hash format from register and login.**
already i try various way but not sucessfull. so any body help me.

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/admin-panel';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        return redirect()->to('admin-login');
        //$this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

Comment: You want to remove the password hash? As in, you want to store plaintext passwords?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Disable hashing on Auth::attempt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47058797/disable-hashing-on-authattempt)

Answer (score 3):

In App\Http\Controllers\Auth\Registercontroller.php

Scroll down and in the create function 
remove `'password' => Hash::make($data['password']),` 
to `'password' => $data['password'],`

For the login copy paste this into LoginController:

```
protected function attemptLogin(Request $request)
{
    $user = User::where('email', $request->username)
        ->where('password', $request->password)
        ->first();

    if(!isset($user)){
        return false;
    }

    Auth::login($user);

    return true;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your help but i want to know how to remove hash when login user

Comment: @MithunRana adjusted my answer

Answer (score 1):

**I'm going to preface this by saying MAKE SURE YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING. This is extremely dangerous. You should never, in any circumstance, store passwords without hashing them.**

---

In your `LoginController.php`, override the login function from the `AuthenticatesUsers.php`. Copy what's already in `AuthenticatesUsers.php`, because we only really need to worry about the call to the `attempt()` function.

I am going to assume that you are not hashing stored passwords, in which case you only need to check if the supplied password is equal to the password you have stored.

You will want to first get the user with the username they entered, so `$user = User::whereUsername($request->input('username'))->first();` then validate their stored password against the input, so `$user->password === $request->input('password');`. You then need to use the `Auth` facade to authenticate the user, so that the rest of the `AuthenticatesUsers.php` trait can work effectively.

There are going to be some changes depending on how you've set up your user model, but the below should give you the gist of things.

The whole thing should look like this:

```php
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\User;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Auth;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = '/home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }

    public function login(Request $request)
    {
        $this->validateLogin($request);

        // If the class is using the ThrottlesLogins trait, we can automatically throttle
        // the login attempts for this application. We'll key this by the username and
        // the IP address of the client making these requests into this application.
        if (method_exists($this, 'hasTooManyLoginAttempts') &&
            $this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {
            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);

            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }

        $user = User::whereUsername($request->input('username'))
            ->wherePassword($request->input('password'))
            ->first();

        if ($user !== null) {
            Auth::login($user);
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request);
        }

        // If the login attempt was unsuccessful we will increment the number of attempts
        // to login and redirect the user back to the login form. Of course, when this
        // user surpasses their maximum number of attempts they will get locked out.
        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);
    }
}
```